# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime error when viewing JPEG files in Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, camera, jpeg, exif, visual-c++

I am getting the following error each time I view JPG files in the windows explorer in Detailed view. It also appears when you open the properties of the file. I'm using Windows 8.

---

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE File: multimedia\photos\metadatahandler\util.cpp Line: 4706

Expression: MinutesFraction < 1.0

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)
```

---

These pictures were taken from a Nikon Coolpix AW110 camera. I think it is related to some EXIF data that is a date/time.

I have tried reinstalling the Visual C++ 2013 and 2008 Run time library and restarting and the problem is still there.

I uploaded a sample file here: https://anonfiles.com/file/e346e174708714a88d372e295265a03f (click topmost download button and not the ad below it or just save the opened image)

**UPDATE:**

Running "jhead.exe -purejpg" command on the file removed the problem at the expense of losing exif data. I tried running "jhead -v" on the unmodified file and it showed the following:

```
Exif header 64069 bytes long
Exif section in Intel order
(dir has 12 entries)
    ImageDescription = "                               "
    Make = "NIKON"
    Model = "COOLPIX AW110  "
    Orientation = 1
    XResolution = 300/1
    YResolution = 300/1
    ResolutionUnit = 2
    Software = "COOLPIX AW110V1.1              "
    DateTime = "2014:08:21 13:13:25"
    YCbCrPositioning = 2
    ExifOffset = 280
    Exif Dir:(dir has 36 entries)
        ExposureTime = 10/3200
        FNumber = 39/10
        ExposureProgram = 2
        ISOSpeedRatings = 125
        Unknown Tag 8830 Value = 1
        ExifVersion = "0230"
        DateTimeOriginal = "2014:08:21 13:13:25"
        DateTimeDigitized = "2014:08:21 13:13:25"
        ComponentsConfiguration = "?"
        CompressedBitsPerPixel = 2/1
        ExposureBiasValue = 0/10
        MaxApertureValue = 39/10
        MeteringMode = 5
        LightSource = 0
        Flash = 24
        FocalLength = 50/10
        Maker note:  4e 69 6b 6f 6e 00 02 00 00 00 49... (10406 bytes)
        UserComment = "?
                                                               "
        FlashPixVersion = "0100"
        ColorSpace = 1
        ExifImageWidth = 2272
        ExifImageLength = 1704
        InteroperabilityOffset = 1308
        Interop Dir:(dir has 2 entries)
            InteropIndex = "R98"
            InteropVersion = "0100"
        FileSource = ""
        SceneType = ""
        CustomRendered = 0
        ExposureMode = 0
        WhiteBalance = 0
        DigitalZoomRatio = 0/100
        FocalLengthIn35mmFilm = 28
        SceneCaptureType = 0
        GainControl = 4
        Contrast = 0
        Saturation = 0
        Sharpness = 0
        SubjectDistanceRange = 1
    GPS Dir offset = 942
    GPS info dir:(dir has 13 entries)
        GPSVersionID        =02, 03, 00, 00, 03, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00,
 01, 00, 02
        GPSLatitudeRef      =""
        GPSLatitude         =0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0
        GPSLongitudeRef     =""
        GPSLongitude        =0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0
        GPSAltitudeRef      =00
        GPSAltitude         =0/0
        GPSTimeStamp        =0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0
        GPSSatellites       =""
        GPSImgDirectionRef  =""
        GPSImgDirection     =0/0
        GPSMapDatum         =""
        GPSDateStamp        =""
    Continued directory (dir has 6 entries)
        Compression = 6
        XResolution = 300/1
        YResolution = 300/1
        ResolutionUnit = 2
        ThumbnailOffset = 12788
        ThumbnailLength = 3605
Thumbnail size: 3605 bytes
Approximate quality factor for qtable 0: 95 (scale 9.93, var 1.25)
Approximate quality factor for qtable 1: 95 (scale 10.34, var -1.36)
Approximate quality factor for qtable 2: 95 (scale 10.34, var -1.41)
JPEG image is 2272w * 1704h, 3 color components, 8 bits per sample
File name    : dscn0242.jpg
File size    : 853333 bytes
File date    : 2014:08:21 13:13:24
Camera make  : NIKON
Camera model : COOLPIX AW110
Date/Time    : 2014:08:21 13:13:25
Resolution   : 2272 x 1704
Flash used   : No (auto)
Focal length :  5.0mm  (35mm equivalent: 28mm)
Exposure time: 0.0031 s  (1/320)
Aperture     : f/3.9
ISO equiv.   : 125
Whitebalance : Auto
Metering Mode: pattern
Exposure     : program (auto)
Focus range  : macro
GPS Latitude :
GPS Longitude:
GPS Altitude :  0.00m
```

I can't pinpoint what particular data is causing the problem here. It seems fine.

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: Windows 8. Sorry forgot to add that. Firmware of Nikon Coolpix AW110 is the latest 1.1.

Comment: I guess you should try downloading [all the latest](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019667) (including 2010) VC++ Redistributable packages and see if that helps.

Comment: What are the list of programs installed on your computer? Do you have anything that adds context menu handlers for JPG files? Something like MediaInfo? Anyway, you might want to try running the commands `sfc /scannow` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and see if that helps

Comment: Can you reproduce the errors on your side or is it only on my side? All windows update are installed already. I don't get the issue with other JPEG files or JPEG fles from other cameras--only these. Can you open the file properties without getting this error? I already did "sfc /scannow" before and no files were fixed. I will try the other suggestions later.

Comment: @PrinceKitts When you're done trying, another thing you can do is to strip the EXIF data from the image. To do so, make a copy of the picture, download [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/jhead.exe), then open a command prompt and run the following command: `"X:\Path\to\jhead.exe" -purejpg "Y:\folder\containing\picture.jpg"`

Comment: I used jhead to strip all exif data. it removed the problem but at the expense of losing exif data.

Comment: I added some info in the question to show exif data extracted using jhead.

Comment: @PrinceKitts Yes, that was just to confirm the EXIF data was the culprit. The problem it's either the camera which is writing some sort of malformed data or a bug in the Windows built-in metadata handler. I can't reproduce the issue using Windows 7 SP1 or 8.1 Update, so I guess it's the latter. Consider [updating to Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial) and [installing the latest updates](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/install-latest-update-windows-8-1).

Comment: @and31415 Thanks. You were of great help. I would vote on your answer but can't as it's just a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have a buggy [property handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266532(v=vs.85).aspx) registered for the jpeg file type. You can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to find out which program is handling the jpeg file type and try to contact the program's developer, or uninstall the program.

An assert failure indicates the buggy program has a bug caught by a bug trap which uses the runtime's [assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) function to report the bug. The assert function reported the source code location of the error but that is only useful to the author of the program. Reinstalling the runtime won't remove the bug trap which is in the application itself. You can submit the error location and your picture files to help the developer of the property handler to find the problem faster.

Comment: The property handler involved was the "IPropertyStore Handler for Images". It is a Microsoft Windows Handler using the file "C:\Windows\system32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll". Some info about it--Type: Property Handler, Description: "Photo Metadata", Version: "6.2.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)". I disabled this and the problem disappeared at the expense of not being able to see detailed metadata or properties of the file such as dimensions, date taken, etc. So it is probably a bug in Windows? It only occurs on images from the Nikon Coolpix AW110. On other cameras, it's fine.

Comment: I added EXIF info of the file using jhead in the question. It might be of help.